# How can I compile opencv3 for java on windows?

Tags: java, opencv, sift, surf

I want to use **OpenCV** on Java. In fact, I want to use **SIFT/SURF** of OpenCV on Java. Based on documents on the web, I understood SIFT and SURF don't exist in compiled OpenCV. I decided to compile it myself. I followed instruction from [this link](https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/building-java-wrapper-for-opencv/). I done all steps perfectly, I run `mingw32-make` on `cmd` (in administrator mode) and everything seemed to be good, but when progress went to about 90% and it was going to create `opencv-310.jar`, following error occurred:

[image]

I use these:

- Wndows7-64bit
- cmake-3.6.2
- mingw-w64 (x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1)
- apache-ant-1.9.7
- jdk1.8.0_101

Any idea?